# Hacked Azure VM, how to recover data?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, recovery

I believe a virtual machine I was running got hacked, because the username and password doesn't work. I think the server banned my computer because I tried the old password too much, so I tried from other devices, and it still doesn't work. I saw [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/92a55a09-19c9-4731-b7a6-2b1a9ea909f7/forgotten-vm-password), and it says that I can't change password from Azure management portal, but I can recover my data. How exactly do I do that?

**Update**: I got it to work the way mentioned in the link, with help from Chad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A virtual machine is based on an image in a storage container.  It takes a bit to track down the right VHD, but if it is one that MS created for you, it should be something like name_of_your_CloudService_name_of_your_VM.vhd, and it will probably be in the VHDs container.

You could download this VHD and bring it up in something like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), or you could try spinning up another VM based on that image.  Either way, your data should all still be there provided you are able to log into the machine.

EDIT:
As your link suggests, deleting your corrupt VM, spinning up a new VM and attaching the disk would be a good way to get access to your data.  Simply click on the "Attach" button at the bottom of the virtual machines section of your dashboard of your new VM and choose existing disk.  Browse to the VM and attach.

Comment: If I create a new VM on azure with that image, in the creation process, will I be able to choose the new username and password?

Comment: And also, it is about 30GB in size, and my current connection isn't good, so that would take way too long and therefore downloading isn't an option

Comment: No, when you choose a "Disk" it just spins it up with no changes.  If you've sysprepped an image then you can specify the username when you create the VM.

Comment: I'm not sure of the severity of your hacking, but if you really have lost access to the VM on azure, pulling down the image to fix it might be your only option.  Much like having a problem that requires you to be physically at the machine you've co-located.

Comment: Several articles that i've read speak of creating a secondary user before you sysprep an image to be uploaded (because sysprep disables the admin user).  It sounds like this is a good practice for the auto generated ones as well.

Comment: To sysprep an image, I need to be able log in to my server right?

Comment: Yes, its run from the command line on Win7 machines or higher

Comment: Ok, then how will I run it? I can't connect to my server. And it's linux, by the way.

Comment: My apologies, sysprep is a windows tool.  My only thoughts are to download the image, attach it as a hard drive to a machine or virtual machine, and go digging in the system files to find the problem.  Wish i had better ideas for you.

Comment: And the answer to the question in the link I gave, won't that help. Do you have any idea what the author meant with that answer?

Comment: Yes, that would help.  Spin up another vm and attach the corrupt disk as a resource to the new vm.  In windows it would make it another drive automatically, i'm not sure if you would need to mount it on a linux drive.

Comment: When I try to attach something to the new vm, there is only "Attach empty disk". Do I need to delete the malfunctioning vm first, so that the disk can be used, or something?

Comment: I deleted the vm, but I can't do anything with the disk right now. I can't delete, can't attach it to a vm, and can't create a new vm with it. I think this had happened to me before, and I had to wait a while. Is that normal?

Comment: Ok, I managed to attach the disk to a new vm, and then mounted it, and now I'm copying the files. :)